# How to add something to current_user with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, controller

I have devise installed and the rspec setup ready for using controller_macros

My ControllerMacro:

```
  def login_user
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      @current_user = Fabricate(:user)
      @current_user.confirm! # or set a confirmed_at inside the factory. Only necessary if you are using the confirmable module
      sign_in @current_user
    end
  end
```

and my payment_controller_spec.rb

```
describe PaymentController do
 describe "payment" do
    login_user
    before(:each) do
      @current_user.payments.create(method: "bank", amount: "123")

    end

    it 'should assign amount_to_pay' do

      get :bank_payment, { id: @current_user.to_param}

      expect(assigns[:amount_to_pay]).to eq "123"
    end
  end
end
```

Error Message

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `payments' for nil:NilClass
```

**How can I access the `@current_user` within my specs and add some dependencies?**

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this in your controller macro:

```
def stub_accessibility(user)
  controller.stub(:current_user).and_return(user)
end
```

Then in your controller specs:

```
let(:user) { User.new }

before do
  stub_accessibility(user)
end
```

This way you can play with your `user` around in your controller specs' context.

Comment: If I put ```stub_accessibility(user)``` into the before block I got an ```undefined method stub_accessibility for ``` (I restarted the spork server)

Comment: You need to define the `stub_accessiblity` method yourself in a module that you include in your `spec_helper.rb` file ;)

Comment: I have implemented this (described on the devise wiki) and also use the login_user method successfully.